# SSH tunnel? How to get access?

Tags: ssh-tunneling

My remote application has debug port opened `5005` on a remote host (call them `rmt.dev.host`). The issue is I can get access to the `rmt.dev.host` only through `ssh`-port.

Is it possible to make ssh tunnel to access 5005 port from my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -L option does exactly that:

```
ssh -L 5005:localhost:5005 rmt.dev.host
```

The port 5005 on your machine will be tunnelled to the port 5005 on the remote host (`localhost` above is considered relatively to the ssh server).